# Setting iOS splash image not possible in Sencha Touch + phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, extjs, splash-screen

I have looked around on the web for answers but and am unable to find a clear way to set the iOS splash screen from the sencha/phonegap config. I created splash images to both sencha and phonegap resource directories, and added them to sencha's app.json and config.xml as shown below, then ran "sencha app refresh && sencha app build native".

```
<gap:splashgap:platform="ios"width="320"height="480"src="resources/splash/320x480.png" />
<gap:splashgap:platform="ios"width="640"height="960"src="resources/splash/640x960.png" />
<gap:splashgap:platform="ios"width="640"height="1136"src="resources/splash/640x1136.png" />
<gap:splashgap:platform="ios"width="768"height="1024"src="resources/splash/768x1024.png" />
<gap:splashgap:platform="ios"width="1024"height="768"src="resources/splash/1024x768.png" />
<gap:splashgap:platform="ios"width="1536"height="2048"src="resources/splash/1536x2048.png" />
<gap:splashgap:platform="ios"width="2048"height="1536"src="resources/splash/2048x1536.png" />
```

This workflow works well to update the app icon files in the Xcode project, but does not update the iOS splash screen.

Is this actually not possible??

Thanks!

Comment: The same configuration works for me. What version of phonegap you are using?  I tested with 3.5.0.